# Jasmine test input with pattern

Tags: angularjs, forms, unit-testing, jasmine

I have a form with the following input:

`<input type="email" name="email" ng-model="register.form.email" ng-pattern="emailRegex">`

I want to test that the form is invalid if the user types an invalid email:

```
it('...', function() {
    form.email.$setViewValue('invalid');
    expect(form.email.$valid).toBeFalsy(); // OK
    form.email.$setViewValue('invalid@');    
    expect(form.email.$valid).toBeFalsy(); // OK
    form.email.$setViewValue('invalid@host');     
    expect(form.email.$valid).toBeFalsy(); // Not OK    
});
```

The last expectatijon fails because the input is valid, although the email regex expects a domain. It feels as if the pattern is not used in my test because when I change the type to text, it already fails at the first expectation. How can I make sure the pattern is picked up in the tests?

For completeness, this is the regex (not written by me):

`^[_A-Za-z0-9-]+(\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@[_A-Za-z0-9]+[_A-Za-z0-9-]*[_A-Za-z0-9]+(\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$`

Changing the type to `text` didn't work.

I'm using jasmine 2.4.1 and angular 1.4.2. I'm using ngHtml2JsPreprocessor as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25022663/how-to-unit-test-angular-form) to initialize the form in my tests.

**Edit:**

This is how to form is initialized:

```
beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $templateCache, $compile) {
   var $scope = $rootScope.$new();
    vm = $controller('RegisterController', {$scope: $scope});
    var templateHtml = $templateCache.get("register.html");
    var template = angular.element("<div>" + templateHtml + "</div>");
    $compile(template)($scope);
    var form = $scope.registerForm;
    $scope.$apply();
    scope = $scope;
}));
```

Comment: What that test will proof? That `ng-pattern` works? Yes - it works, probably the team responsive for developing AngularJS will catch that error before you. You want to test regExp? Extract it and test it in unit test

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AngularJS still works in the way, how it was developed

```js
angular.module('app', [])

describe('Registration form', () => {
  'use strict'

  beforeEach(module('app'))

  let form
  let scope

  beforeEach(inject(($rootScope, $compile) => {
    scope = $rootScope.$new()
    var formElem = ['<form name="registrationForm">',
      '<input type="text" name="number" ng-model="input" ng-pattern="/^[_A-Za-z0-9-]+(\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@[_A-Za-z0-9]+[_A-Za-z0-9-]*[_A-Za-z0-9]+(\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$/">',
      '</form>'
    ].join('')
    $compile(formElem)(scope)
    form = scope.registrationForm
  }))

  it('has no `$valid` state', () => {
    expect(form.$valid).toBeTruthy()
    form.number.$setViewValue('invalid email address')
    expect(form.number.$valid).toBeFalsy()
  })

  it('has `$valid` state', () => {
    expect(form.$valid).toBeTruthy()
    form.number.$setViewValue('some@valid.address')
    expect(form.number.$valid).toBeTruthy()
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://safjanowski.github.io/jasmine-jsfiddle-pack/pack/jasmine-2.0.3-concated.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-mocks.js"></script>
<link href="https://safjanowski.github.io/jasmine-jsfiddle-pack/pack/jasmine.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Comment: As you've shown it does work as I was expecting, so I'm going to start from your example and build up my test case. In regards to your other comment: sadly I do have to write this particular test even though I know it's not that useful. Many thanks!

Comment: Some usufull regExp that you can use to validate email address -  http://emailregex.com/

Answer (score 0):

I think you should call `scope.$digest();` after using `form.email.$setViewValue`, `scope` beeing the scope passed to your $compile. That's what I used in every tests.

You can also see more infos right here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/22772504/4583079

Comment: I've tried that and unfortunately it doesn't work. I can see that prior to the last expectation, the `modelValue` is already `invalid@host`which means it has already passed the parsers and validators (if I remember correctly).