# How do I write a unit test in an Angularjs Directive

Tags: angularjs-directive

I have written a directive to validate the input. How do I write a unit test for this directive?

```
angular.module('validationModule', [])
    .directive('validateName', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            require: '?ngModel',
            link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
                if (!ngModel) return;
                ngModel.$parsers.unshift(function (inputValue) {
                    var expr = inputValue.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]/g, "");
                    ngModel.$viewValue = expr;
                    ngModel.$render();
                    return expr;
                });
            }
        };
    });
```

Comment: This one helped me...

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15219717/to-test-a-custom-validation-angular-directive

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://www.yearofmoo.com/2013/01/full-spectrum-testing-with-angularjs-and-karma.html) might be a good place to start.