# Unit Testing Custom Directive. A Password validation. AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, angularjs-directive, passwords, karma-runner

I have this AngularJs Directive and i need to do a unit test for this using karma-jasmine tester. The directive matches two input fields and sets the form valid if the two input text matches. ( a password validator)

```js
angular.module('UserValidation', []).directive('validPasswordC', function () {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
            ctrl.$parsers.unshift(function (viewValue, $scope) {
                var noMatch = viewValue != scope.myForm.password.$viewValue;
                ctrl.$setValidity('noMatch', !noMatch)
            })
        }
    }
});
```

And this is my HTML form

```html
  <form name='myForm'>
      <!-- other stuff  -->
        
    <label>Password</label><br/>
    <input type='password'ng-model='password' name='password' required  ng-minlength="8" ng-maxlength="20" ng-pattern="/(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[^a-zA-Z])(?=.*[!@#$%^&*><.+_])/" />
    <label for="password_c">Confirm Password</label>
    <input type="password" id="password_c" name="password_c" ng-model="formData.password_c" valid-password-c required  />
    
    <!-- other stuff here -->
          
     <button ng-click='adduser()' class="btn btn-default" ng-disabled="!myForm.$valid"> Add User </button>
        
    </form>
```

and this is the TEST case i'm trying

```js
describe("should match the password", function () {
   var scope, myform;
   beforeEach(module('UserValidation'));
   beforeEach(inject(function ($compile, $rootScope) {
    scope=$rootScope;
    var element = angular.element(
        '<form name="myForm">' +
       '<input type="password" id="password_c" name="password_c" ng-model="formData.password_c" valid-password-c required  />' +
       '</form>'
    );
       scope.model = {some: null };
       $compile(element)(scope);
       scope.$digest();
       myform = scope.myForm;
   }));
    it('should validate the directive', function () {
       //how do i test this when it actually validates two input fields
      // i cant seem to find out how, PS im new to angular
    })



});
```

Comment: This should help.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15219717/to-test-a-custom-validation-angular-directive