# Visual Studio Locals and Watch contradict

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, visual-studio-2015, jasmine, chutzpah

I'm using Visual Studio 2015. I've installed both Chutzpah extensions. I've configured Chutzpah to use Jasmine. I've already got a dummy test working. Now I'm trying to test some AngularJS code. I've been following [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15219717/1680677), but I've come across a bizarre problem:

[image: Visual Studio Locals and Watch 1 contradict each other.]

The Watch tab indicates that `form.ssn` is undefined, but I can see the same being defined in the Locals tab. Unfortunately for me, the test evaluates `form.ssn` as undefined, throws an exception, and fails. How can I get this test to work as expected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel *so* stupid. The input in the HTML was named snn, not ssn.